In C++, why is the function qualifier applied to member functions in member function pointers, rather than to the class itself?
Why use this form, even though it may lead to seemingly "invalid" types like int() const? Does int (const Class::*)() cause fewer problems?

"this form" Can you provide an example?

@Chris I mean the current c++ syntax，like int (Class::*)() const

Probably because it mirrors the way the method is defined.

@Barmar It's pure. What about the second part? Would it be better to move the qualifier to class?

Abominable function types exists :/ see https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0172r0.html

Are you concerned just about syntax, or with underlying Abominable function types? For the former, if it is just syntax, i.e rules/traits to remove class would be the same logically.for the later, above paper tr to limit some issue with them.

@Jarod42 I focus more on the latter.In addition to the way I just mentioned, my assumption is that the qualifier must be bound to the class, that is, if you remove the class , the qualifier will not exist.But one of the use cases in this article also undermines this assumption, and I have to wonder if there is a better way.
